# Error 10 logging in with Google @ Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, oauth, kotlin, google-oauth

I've seen other questions where people have the same error. I've tried to follow the same steps as the other people, but **nothing I've tried have worked**.

**I've tried ussing different client ids** (with the SHA-1 fingerprint @ the **debug.keystore** and @ the **signed apk keystore**, also the **client-id my server uses** for oauth, none of them have worked out).

I probably have an stupid mistake in my code but I've not been able to see what I've to change

```
package es.boresoft.slate

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
import android.content.Intent
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import java.util.*
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast


class login : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun rand(from: Int, to: Int) : Int { val random = Random(); return random.nextInt(to - from) + from }
    var RC_SIGN_IN = rand(1,1000) // this generate a random int between 1 and 1000, WORKING OK

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_id_backend)) // *1
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        /* 1:
        I'm using the server client id but I also have available: 
        - "google_id_debug" (for the .android debug.keystore)
        - "google_id" (for the signed apk keystore)
         */

        val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        fun signIn() {
            val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        }


        sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val idToken = account.idToken

            toast("Hola, ${account.displayName}")

            // have not been able to execute this bit of the code, because I get the error all the times

        } catch (e: ApiException) {

            toast("Ha ocurrido un error: ${e.statusCode}. Por favor, vuelva a inentarlo.")

            //TODO: HERE IS WHERE I CAN SEE THE ERROR (10)

        }

    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) { // if the retrieved code is the same as the sent one: OK. WORKING OK
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task) // sends the result to the function above
        } else {
            toast("Ha ocurrido un error. Por favor, vuelva a inentarlo.")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here you can see my strings.xml file, where all the client_ids can be found

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Slate</string>
    <string name="google_id">301769868848-q9fp2tbupvicbjjk8s6rc5uo8k0db4rl.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="google_id_debug">301769868848-oaqf8eigalh3n16c8rdi66gsvlett5df.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="google_id_backend">301769868848-2loutu89gdvhbi4du8foga8kmt6utb9t.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
</resources>
```

Also, I've checked multiple times that the package name is the same one as the one which is specified in the api console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.boresoft.slate">
...
```

---

**Here you can see my api console setup:**
[image]

**Slate Android & Debug: Slate Android**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work in release mode? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/498#issuecomment-286251592

Comment: Nope, it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the package name was not corrently setup @ the gradle file [applicationId]
[image]

Now fixed ;)!